# HTTP GET or HTTP POST or HTTP PUT, Android

Tags: android, http, asp.net-web-api

This is my first attempt at using web APIs. I am trying to implement this PRIVO API for display name https://github.com/Privo/PRIVO-Hub/wiki/Web-Services-API-Reference#update-user-display-name. As you can see, there is not much explanation or code examples.

What I am trying to do is use HTTP GET to receive a valid response which indicates that the name is correct format, and then I should save this display name on our google servers. I only need help with the first half. I'll figure out how to save onto cloud servers later.

The problem I face is that I am not sure if this is how to use HTTP GET, and I am not 100% sure I am not suppose to use POST or PUT either. This is what I have so far, please let me know what I am doing incorrectly.

```
AsyncHttpClient client = null;
String authorizationHeader = "token_type", "" + " " + "access_token", "");
client.addHeader("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
client.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
client.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
String requestBody = "displayName=" + "hardcodedDisplayName";
String requestURL = "https://privohub.privo.com/api/" + "account/public/saveDisplayName?" + requestBody;
client.get(requestURL, new ResponseHandler(myClass.this, "displayName", new OnResponseHandler() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, String apiName, JSONObject response) {
   if (statusCode == 200) {
      Log.i(TAG, "Seems to be working")

   }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(int statusCode, String apiName, String responseMessage) {
   Log.i(TAG, "Fail: " + responseMessage); 
}

@Override
public void onFailure(int statusCode, String apiName, JASONArray errorResponse) {
   Log.i(TAG, "Fail: " + errorResponse);
}

@Override
public void onFailure(int statusCode, String apiName, JSONObject errorResponse) {
   if (errorResponse != null) {
      Log.i(TAG, "Fail: " + errorResponse);
   }
}

}));
```

I am getting the following response in result of the above code

{"message":"Object not found","validationErrors":[],"responseTimestamp":1419278367177,"totalCount":-1,"status":"failed","resultCount":-1,"entity":null}

What does this response mean? It failed on the onFailure(int statusCode, String apiName, JSONObject errorResponse) and the error code is 404

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use whatever method the API documentation says you should use. Which in this case is neither GET or POST, but PUT!

Comment: I see this mistake now. However, can you provide an example? Is the methodology similar to GET? Can I simply change get to put is what I mean?

Comment: Yes, client.put() should work. Perhaps it's needed to encode the parameter as a RequestParam object instead of appending to the url.

Comment: This is my first time doing this. Can you show me an example of what you mean by encoding the parameter as a RequestParam object?

Comment: I assume you're using loopj? I don't have experience with that library either, but I am assuming from the javadoc page that you should use onbe of the put methods: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.html  And the javadoc for RequestParam contains examples of how to add parameters: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/RequestParams.html